# Cocoapods: group pod libraries under a company name

Tags: cocoapods

If I want to publish a set of public pods, is there a way to group them under a company name to prevent collision with other pods and to be clear these pods are from the expected company?

I see Firebase is able to do this https://cocoapods.org/pods/Firebase but I don't see anything different in their `.podspec`s that would distinguish this unless it's all based on the spec.author name or the name we set up when we register with trunk?

If we can do this, how do we add maintainers to this group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CocoaPods trunk is a flat namespace and has no grouping mechanism other than strings, which are really only a convention.

The Firebase is an umbrella pod with a set of subspecs that reference other pods that are by convention prefixed with the "Firebase" string. For example the `Firebase/Storage` subspec depends on the `FirebaseStorage` pod.